# How do I tell my Mom I'm Agnostic?

Tags: religion

I'm not a parent but this is a question for parents.

I've been Agnostic for a while now, but my Mother is a Christian, and a very big one at that.

I'm kind of scared to tell her, but that may be my inferiority complex kicking in, so I would like some advice.

Edit: I'm still a young kid, and my Mother is the type of person who thinks she's always right, so I don't know how to go about this without major problems.

Comment: Welcome to Parenting.SE! Questions from a child's perspective are OK. This question may be useful for you to read [Breaking my rejection of christianity to my parents](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/4684/breaking-my-rejection-of-christianity-to-my-parents) and [How do I tell my parents I'm no longer Christian?](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/7618/how-do-i-tell-my-parents-im-no-longer-christian)— if you think that your situation is different, please revise your Question.

Comment: Also, [How do I tell my mom that I am not Christian?](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/7222/how-do-i-tell-my-mom-that-i-am-not-christian). (You're clearly not alone in this sort of situation!)

Comment: I would recommend a bit more detail here.  In particular, why do you want to tell her?  Are you concerned with avoiding going to church or participating in certain activities you're not comfortable in?  Or are you thinking it's the right thing to do to tell her (but have no other specific reason)?  Or something else?

Comment: Please see [this Meta question](http://meta.parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/884/is-a-question-about-discussion-agnosticism-with-a-religious-parent-a-duplicate) about the duplicate nature of this question. There are three other questions which cover the topic of children and parents having different religions in some way, and the "best fit" is currently linked as the duplicate.